# Curl bash script truncated/ merging

Tags: linux, bash, curl

My aim is to have bash scripts get up to get a token from a WEB API and parse that token into a post command which will then create an new account (based on user input) on that WEB API. It succesffuly gets the token but when I reference the variable in my POST command, it either cuts it off or merges it into the  tab. Has anyone seen this happen before?

I have read a similar issue where the issue was the content header, I have removed that but it hasnt fixed the issue.

A warning...I am a learner so my code isn't the best!

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl --insecure -X POST \
  https://192.168.XX.XXX:8443/application/token \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
  -H 'Host: 192.168.XX.XX:8443' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'client-key: 123' \
  -H 'client-name: 1234' \
  -H 'client-secret: 123456' \
  -H 'grant_type: OAuth' \
  -d '<request>
    <username>johndoe</username>
    <password>secret</password>
</request>' > tokenNewAcc.xml

grep 'access_token' tokenNewAcc.xml | sed 's/.*://' | sed s/,// |  tr -d '"' > /home/oracle/tokenNewAcc.txt

rm tokenNewAcc.xml

value=`cat /home/oracle/tokenNewAcc.txt`

MYVAR=`cat /home/oracle/testaccounts.txt`

ID=`cut -d' ' -f1  /home/oracle/testaccounts.txt`
FNAME=`cut -d' ' -f2  /home/oracle/testaccounts.txt`
LNAME=`cut -d' ' -f3 /home/oracle/testaccounts.txt`
EMAIL=`cut -d' ' -f4  /home/oracle/testaccounts.txt`L
\

curl -k -X POST \
  https://192.168.XX.XXX:8443/application/accounts \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
  -H 'Host: 192.168.XX.XXX:8443' \
  -H "auth: "$value"" \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '<request>
<userid'$ID'</userid>
<firstname>'$FNAME'</firstname>
<lastname>'$LNAME'</lastname>
<email>'$EMAIL'</email>
</request>'


OUTPUT of POST where it has trouble:

curl -k -X POST https://192.168.36.XXX:8443/cloudminder/accounts -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -H 'Host: 192.168.36.1' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -d '<request>ad9f23295b6
<useridconnectortest</userid>
<firstname>conn</firstname>
<lastname>connect</lastname>
<email>connectorL</email>
</request>'
```

As you can see, the host url is cut off, the beginning of the token (ad9f23295b6) merges into the request.

Comment: Your quoting style is weird and may be part of the problem. Use `"text $variable text"` when you need variables expanded, in particular with your `<request>` : by using the variables unquoted (e.g. `'text '$variable'text'`) you risk word splitting if the variable expands to something that contains spaces, tabs or linefeeds. `"auth: "$value""` should probably be `"auth: \"$value\""` if you need literal double-quotes arounds the value.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to check your `$value` and/or the file you extract the parts of the request for control characters. You can for instance use `xxd` to check the hexadecimal content of your strings to make sure they don't contain hidden characters such as `\r` which could explain your weird behaviour (e.g. the string "foo\rbar" would be displayed as "bar" since `\r` makes you return to the start of the line before carrying on writing)